# Jquery and animate, cant get classes to change properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get this work, but can not understand, what causing the problems.

- Active divs dissapear on mouseover
- active div wont appear after
  first class change

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/3/

need any help. thx

Answer (score 1):

Your code looked quite complex so I've cut it right back to basics and then applied simple styling/jQuery animate effects.  So:

```
<div class='slogan_switch'>
    <div class='slogan_switch_item inactive'>
        <div class='ssi_arrow_active'><div class='ssi_arrow_inactive'></div></div>
        <div class='ssi_text_left'></div>
        <div class='ssi_text_body'>Test Text</div>
        <div class='ssi_text_right'></div>
    </div>
    ....etc
</div>
```

has been changed to a more semantic, and cleaner/leaner, unordered list:

```
<ul class='slogan_switch'>
    <li><a href="#">Test Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Text 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Text 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've not implemented all of the effects you had going on in your initial fiddle, but hopefully this is something you can work on a little to finish off in style!
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/4/

Updated:
Following on from your comment, I've amended the jQuery to allow an element to be active on page load and then to activate the other elements on hover:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/13/

Comment: thx, but it still does not work with my complexer example. I need to switch classes. The hovered element must stay active after mouseout, and all other elements must switch to inactive. I think, i have some problems with switching classes.

Comment: It's much easier to see the problem now http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/7/ How does it have to work: one element is active on load. If some inactive element is hovered with mouse, it becomes active, and the active on becomes inactive.

Comment: @Sobakinet - Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/13/  This has an element activated on page load, and then updates as other elements are hovered.  I've added this fiddle to my post above too.